# GEE: Batch Download S2 Image Collection with pixel values = NoData

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am downloading the S2 image collection with all the bands(Band 1-Band 12)based on multiple boundaries.  The code is working well and it manages to download the GeoTiff S2 image with all Band 1-Band 12.  However, all the downloaded images have pixel values of NoData when I opened them in ArcMap, QGIS and SNAP.  I try to calculate the statistic for raster but not work too.  What did I do wrong?

Here's my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/41f205709fd0cda8e313d888e47317fb

[image: S2 composite image shows pixel value of NoData]

Comment: Unable to view script. Please use the "Get Link" button on top of the code editor and past the link here.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/41f205709fd0cda8e313d888e47317fb